# Unreal make error : invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld'

Tags: linux, clang, unreal-engine4

Trying to setup Unreal Engine 4.22 on linux 16.04 and i'm having this when using make command:

```
    CrashReportClient Linux Shipping  
    Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
    Setting up Mono
    Building CrashReportClient...
    Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (/home/user/Desktop/UE4/UnrealEngine).
    Creating makefile for CrashReportClient (no existing makefile)
    Waiting for 'git status' command to complete
    Terminating git child process due to timeout
    Building UnrealHeaderTool...
    Performing 2 actions (3 in parallel)
    [1/2] Link (lld) UnrealHeaderTool
    clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld'
    Makefile:212: recipe for target 'CrashReportClient-Linux-Shipping' failed
    make: *** [CrashReportClient-Linux-Shipping] Error 5
```

Clang version :

```
    clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
    Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

I've tried everything I could find on the internet, but this mistake won't go away.
If anyone know ...
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please note that questions here are expected to be programming related, refer to [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question of software installation may be more proper for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).